# Google Map Integration with React Js projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need to use Google Maps API to get this as desired output: `{'hotels','atms','banks','hospitals'}.`

Already tried `google-map-react` but not worked properly.

Requirement it can be any of the below:

- free api
- script
- library.

Reference Image:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Google Maps Javascript's Places Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) to search for the nearby places using different keyword as you mentioned. Here is a [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search-pagination) from Google Maps Doc.

You can also implement it in reactjs using the code snippet below with the similar functionality as your use case.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

let map;
const API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
const coords = { lat: 41.375885, lng: 2.177813 };
let markers = [];

class NearbySearchApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (!window.google) {
      const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.type = "text/javascript";
      script.src =
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` +
        API_KEY +
        `&libraries=geometry,places`;
      script.id = "googleMaps";
      script.async = true;
      script.defer = true;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      script.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        this.renderMap();
      });
    } else {
      this.renderMap();
    }
  }

  renderMap() {
    const el = document.getElementById("map");

    if (el) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        zoom: 14,
        center: {
          lat: coords.lat,
          lng: coords.lng,
        },
      });

      return map;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleClick(data) {
    //clearing markers and marker array everytime a keyword is clicked
    for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      markers[i].setMap(null);
    }
    markers = [];


    document.getElementById("chosen").innerHTML =
      "You clicked: " + data.keyword;

    //NearbySearch function  
    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(
      { location: coords, radius: 500, type: [data.keyword] },
      function (results, status, pagination) {
        if (status !== "OK") return;
        const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (let i = 0, place; (place = results[i]); i++) {
          //creating markers icon per type of place
          let image = {
            url: place.icon,
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
          };
          //creates marker for every place result
          const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location,
          });
          //putting markers in the array
          markers.push(marker);
          //showing markers from the array in the map
          for (let i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
          }

          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      }
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section>
        <h1>ADD YOUR API KEY TO MAKE IT WORK</h1>

        <div id="map" />
        <div id="panel">
          <h3 id="chosen">Please choose a Place:</h3>
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { keyword: "atm" })}
            value="ATM"
          /><br/>
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { keyword: "hospital" })}
            value="Hospital"
          /><br/>
          <input
            type="button"
            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null, { keyword: "store" })}
            value="store"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

export default NearbySearchApp;
```

You can use the `export default` to export NearbySearchApp and import it to another script file like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import NearbySearchApp from './NearbySearchApp';

ReactDOM.render(<NearbySearchApp />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Here's a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sample-nearby-search-app-ksw4xv?file=index.js) that implements this. Make sure to use your API key for the sample code to work properly.